# Installing OpenGL on netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, opengl, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to create an java app using openGL on netbeans 8.2. However the only place I have found a way to use openGL on netbeans is through the netbeans openGL Pack:
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3260/netbeans-opengl-pack
However this was originally desinged for netbeans 6. I found several reports saying that it worked for netbeans 7, so I attempted to install it. I was able to install all parts of it except the GLSL Editor. When I do try install this, I get this pop-up:

---

Some plugins require plugin Editor Library to be installed.
The plugin Editor Library is requested in version >= 1.29.2.8.2 (release version 1) but only 3.49.2.22.43 (of release version different from 1) was found.  The following plugin is affected:       GLSL editor

---

I cannot find any way to downgrade to editor library release 1(which I probably wouldn't want to do) or install editor library 3 and 1 at the same time. Can anyone tell me a way to successfully intall GLSL Editor and Netbeans OpenGL Pack?

Comment: Question is: even if you manage to install it, would it still be useful to you? Development on this opengl pack seems to have stopped almost immediately after it was created around 6 years ago; that means that its OpenGL support will also have stood still for 6 years. Wouldn't using up to date frameworks/toolkits such as LWJGL or LibGDX be more what you are after?

Comment: The Problem with LWJGL is that all documentation I can find on LWJGL requires OpenGL as well. Might look into LibGDX.

Comment: That is no wonder, since LWJGL is a thin wrapper around OpenGL. And so is JOGL that the opengl pack was based around. If you don't want to program directly against the API you indeed need higher level tooling, which is the territory of "engines".